# Why is not feasible to uninstall an operating system the same way it is installed?

Tags: operating-systems, uninstall

I, as someone that work with IT stuff, am asked every other time to re-install OS's, install OS's and replace OS's. But, why I can't uninstall an operating system within itself? Why they don't include a tool or option to allow me to remove it of my system? Why I need to nuke the partition or remove all the files to "uninstall" it?

Comment: It costs less to do it the way it is currently done.

Comment: What would you do with a system without an OS? You will always install another OS on it. And every OS I've come across has the ability to uninstall (read remove/nuke/delete) the previous one. So... why would there be a need for an uninstall?

Answer (score 4):

Because the idea of uninstalling an OS makes no sense. Without an OS, you cannot run programs (including your hypothetical uninstall program).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should clarify what result you expect from uninstalling.

If you want a system that has a blank disk and cannot boot up, then that is just a disk wiping operation, and that's easy to do.

If you want to "undo" the install, and return the system back how it was before the install, then that is more like restoring from a backup.  This would require a second disk to make a backup of the first disk, and that's not going to be there in most systems, and even it were there, it would be a lot of wasted space if you never use it.

In conclusion, there are better tools to accomplish these jobs that already exist.